# Infinitely many numbers not the sum of 27 numbers of the form $a^{28}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I have to prove that there are infinitely many natural numbers that are not the sum of $27$ numbers of the form $a_i^{28}$ with $a_i\in \mathbb{Z}$ (for all $1\leq i \leq 27$).

The proof I came up with seems right, but I'm rather new to number theory, and am not sure. I find it hard to say whether I am allowed to switch to the group $\mathbb{Z}_{29}$ to create my proof.

**Proof**:

Let $S$ be the sum of these $27$ numbers, then $S=\sum_{i=1}^{27} a_i^{28}$. Using Fermat's little theorem, we know that $a_i^{28}=1 (\mod 29)$ when $a_i$ is not divisible by $29$ (for all $1\leq i \leq 27$). When $a_i$ is divisible by $29$, we have $a_i=m\cdot 29$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore we have $a_i^{28} = (m\cdot 29)^{28} = m^{28}\cdot 29^{28} = 0 (\mod 29)$ since $29^{28}$ is divisible by $29$. So $a_i^{28}$ is either $0$ or $1$ when calculating $(\mod 29)$.

Therefore $S (\mod 29) = \sum_{i=1}^{27} a_i^{28} (\mod 29) \neq 28 (\mod 29)$, since the sum of $27$ zeroes or ones is between $0$ and $27$. Therefore all numbers in the residue class $28 (\mod 29)$ are not the sum of $27$ numbers of the form $a_i^{28}$. This residue class contains infinitely many natural numbers. QED.

---

Edit 1: Added index to $a$ to clarify that we are talking about $27$ different $a_i$'s per Winther's comment.

Comment: a nice proof, well done